# What is the correct prometheus URL to be used by prometheus-adapter

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have successfully deployed

- prometheus via helm chart **kube-prometheus-stack** (https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts)
- prometheus-adapter via helm chart **prometheus-adapter** (https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts)

using default configuration with slight customization.

I can access prometheus, grafana and alertmanager, query metrics and see fancy charts.

But prometheus-adapter keeps complaining on startup that it can't access/discover metrics:

```
I0326 08:16:52.266095       1 adapter.go:98] successfully using in-cluster auth
I0326 08:16:52.330094       1 dynamic_serving_content.go:111] Loaded a new cert/key pair for "serving-cert::/var/run/serving-cert/tls.crt::/var/run/serving-cert/tls.key"
E0326 08:16:52.334710       1 provider.go:227] unable to update list of all metrics: unable to fetch metrics for query "{namespace!=\"\",__name__!~\"^container_.*\"}": bad_response: unknown response code 404
```

I've tried various prometheus URLs in the prometheus-adapter Deployment command line argument but  the problem is more or less the same.

E.g. some of the URLs I've tried are

```
--prometheus-url=http://prometheus-operated.prom.svc:9090

--prometheus-url=http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090
```

There are the following services / pods running:

```
$ kubectl -n prom get pods
NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alertmanager-prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running   0          16h
prometheus-adapter-76fcc79b7b-7xvrm                      1/1     Running   0          10m
prometheus-grafana-559b79b564-bh85n                      2/2     Running   0          16h
prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator-8556f58759-kl84l     1/1     Running   0          16h
prometheus-kube-state-metrics-6bfcd6f648-ms459           1/1     Running   0          16h
prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0       2/2     Running   1          16h
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-2x6mt                1/1     Running   0          16h
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-bns9n                1/1     Running   0          16h
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-sbcjb                1/1     Running   0          16h

$ kubectl -n prom get services
NAME                                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
alertmanager-operated                     ClusterIP   None           <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   16h
prometheus-adapter                        ClusterIP   10.0.144.45    <none>        443/TCP                      16h
prometheus-grafana                        ClusterIP   10.0.94.160    <none>        80/TCP                       16h
prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager   ClusterIP   10.0.0.135     <none>        9093/TCP                     16h
prometheus-kube-prometheus-operator       ClusterIP   10.0.170.205   <none>        443/TCP                      16h
prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus     ClusterIP   10.0.250.223   <none>        9090/TCP                     16h
prometheus-kube-state-metrics             ClusterIP   10.0.135.215   <none>        8080/TCP                     16h
prometheus-operated                       ClusterIP   None           <none>        9090/TCP                     16h
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter       ClusterIP   10.0.70.247    <none>        9100/TCP                     16h

kubectl -n kube-system get deployment/metrics-server
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
metrics-server   1/1     1            1           15d
```

Prometheus-adapter helm chart gets deployed using the following values:

```
prometheus:
  url: http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local
certManager:
  enabled: true
```

What is the correct value for `--prometheus-url` for **prometheus-adapter** in my setup ?

Comment: The follow up problem is that I can't see custom metrics that I want to use for HPA. E.g. `kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` results in empty metrics: `{"kind":"APIResourceList","apiVersion":"v1","groupVersion":"custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","resources":[]}`.

Comment: Your URL's seem to be correct. I don't have `prometheus-adapter` deployed but I can curl the URL's (with similar format as yours) from inside a pod. Can you try this? so as to rule out any issues with your cluster dns.

Comment: From within a POD ( in a different namespace ) I can run `wget -O - http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090` and get a HTML response that contains `<title>Prometheus Time Series Collection and Processing Server</title>`.

Comment: Looks about right. Can you edit your question and share the values file for `prometheus-adapter` ?
As for metrics for HPA, wanna start by confirming you have deployed the metrics-server?

Comment: Additionally I tried to query the same configured metric that the prometheus UI uses ( if that is actually a valid URL ). E.g. executing `wget -O - "http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090/api/v1/query?query=%7Bnamespace%21%3D%22%22%2C__name__%21%7E%22%5Econtainer_.*%22%7D&time=1616751935.431"` results in same 404.

Comment: Executing another trivial query fails too - I doubt the URL is correct.
`wget -O - "http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090/api/v1/query?query=kube_pod_info"` results in 404.

Comment: I tried the same request on another k8s cluster and got valid metrics:
`kubectl run -i --tty curl --image=curlimages/curl --rm=true --restart=Never -- sh -c "curl -v 'http://prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090/api/v1/query?query=up' -o -"`
but the same command results in response status 404 on my current cluster.

Comment: A similar query `wget -O - http://prometheus-operator-prometheus.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9090/api/v1/query?query=kube_pod_info` works for me as it does on your different k8s cluster. Something wrong with your original cluster dns it seems then.

Comment: Bang - I'm using additional paths to expose prometheus via Ingress. It seems that this additional path elements need to be added to the URL I'm using to execute a query on prometheus. I.e. the following seems to work and results in metrics data:
`$ kubectl -n prom run -i --tty curl --image=curlimages/curl --rm=true --restart=Never -- sh -c "curl -v 'http://10.244.0.127:9090/monitoring/prometheus/api/v1/query?query=up' -o -"`

Comment: And using the FQDN of prometheus works too: `kubectl -n prom run -i --tty curl --image=curlimages/curl --rm=true --restart=Never -- sh -c "curl -v 'http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090/monitoring/prometheus/api/v1/query?query=up' -o -"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both helm charts (*kube-prometheus-stack* and *prometheus-adapter*).

additional path prefix that works for me is "/", but, prometheus url must be with the name of your helm-install parameter for stack ("helm install ").  I'm using "**prostack**" as stack name. So finally, it works for me:

```
helm install <adapter-name> -n <namespace> --set prometheus.url=http://prostack-kube-prometheus-s-prometheus.monitoring.svc.cluster.local --set prometheus.port=9090 --set prometheus.path=/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the additional path used to expose prometheus via Ingress.

I was using additional path prefix `/monitoring/prometheus/` for my ingress configuration.

The solution is to tell prometheus-adapter too, that prometheus is accessible incl. this path prefix.
Thus the following makes prometheus-adapter happy :

```
--prometheus-url=http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.prom.svc.cluster.local:9090/monitoring/prometheus/
```

And now I can see custom metrics when executing

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Thank you "rock'n rolla" for giving some hints !

Comment: That's the "slight customization" bit I believe you did ;)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue.
When i installed my [prometheus server](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus) with Helm via the community chart.

I got a message like this:

> The Prometheus server can be accessed via port 80 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
> my-tag-prometheus-server.carbon.svc.cluster.local

Please note that is says the service is accessible on port 80 and not 9090 which i had not noticed.

So in my values.yaml file for the [prometheus-adapter](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter) chart i specified port 80 and it worked (instead of the standard 9090)

```
 28 # Url to access prometheus
 29 prometheus:
 30   # Value is templated
 31   url: http://my-tag-prometheus-server.carbon.svc.cluster.local
 32   port: 80
 33   path: ""
```